# Simple XML Error when Parsing Script from External URL

Tags: php, xml

I've got a script that parses an XML file and saves it to a database. I'm attempting to grab the XML file from an external URL but it doesn't work. It does, however, work when I test the script locally. For example, I go to the URL I'm trying to parse, save that file to my computer, upload it to my server and use this script:

```
$url = 'sample_xml/sample.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

It works fine. When I then try to run the same script but I substitute the actually url into the $url variable, I get this error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): Couldn't resolve host name in /foo/foo.php on line 12
```

Is it possible that the server I'm trying to parse from won't allow it? I have no problem pulling the XML file up in a browser window and it's not a password protected site or anything so I'm wondering why simplexml_load_file isn't able to resolve the host name.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try connecting to that url via curl and see if your webserver can reach that site.
If you're running a Security Enhanced version of Linux, the user who is running the command could matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Try to load it with or without "www."

2) Have You tried to load it as described on the PHP web site [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) (I mean using the `file_exists()`)?:

```
<?php
// The file test.xml contains an XML document with a root element
// and at least an element /[root]/title.

if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
?>
```

3) It is stated, that PHP version should be not less than version 5.1.0 (otherwise You need to use `urlencode()`)

4) Does Your URL contains any non-latin characters?

5) On some hosts url access can depend on User-Agent string that requested it.

```
<?php
$url = "http://example.com/"; // replace with your url

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
// the line below makes the common user agent to be present in the request:
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
?>
```

6) Make sure that the IP from which you run the script is not blacklisted

Comment: So I did get a failure notice when doing the above function. Technically the file 'doesn't exists'. The URL string isn't actually using www, it's a subdomain on a site and the file isn't really even an XML file by URL, it's a URL with a bunch of GET variables on it that constructs the XML file when you visit the page (I'm guessing). I am using PHP 5.3.24 and I tried to URL encode the URL and it still failed...

Comment: Have You tried to access that URL with specific User-Agent string? I've updated the fifth item of my answer with a script. That script should output the page to screen.

Comment: I just used the script that you wrote out and I got nothing returned on the page. I checked the source code and nothing is present in the HTML or the console. I checked it on Chrome and Firefox with the same result. Is this basically saying that it can't connect to this file? I had heard of something called 'pseudo XML' as well, not sure if that's what this is...

Comment: Would you be able to jump on a chat? I can't post the URL publicly because they won't want it to show up on a Google search if it shows up on Stack Overflow...thanks so much for your help.